# Jankiness with Chrome mobile's autohiding toolbar and full-height divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a `div` that is resized to be at the full height of the viewport on `load` as well as on `resize`. The problem that I am having is that on Google Chrome for iOS (I haven't checked Android, but I can imagine that it displays the same erratic behaviours) if I scroll down, as usual the address/tab bar scrolls up. And as it does, it fires `resize` events. When that happens, the `div` and its contents jitter and cause scrolling to be come sluggish, as well as causing other oddities with the `div` below.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mseymour/9PEC4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest setting the height of the `.home-hero` only **once** on an smartphone, by either checking the height of the window *(could cause problems, it's inconstant)* or user agent sniffing.

Here are some links:
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)
[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser)

Then set the height only once since on a mobile you cannot really resize the window, and you don't need to resize it on every resize event.

```
if (isMobile) {
    fullScreenSlide(); // resize once
} else {
   setResizeEvent(); // Set the event for multiple resizes
}

function setResizeEvent() {
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        fullScreenSlide();
    }).resize();    
}

function fullScreenSlide () {
  var browserheight = Math.round($(window).height());
  $('.home-hero').height(browserheight);
}
```

*You want to do as little "things" on a smartphone since smartphones are really slow performance wise compared to a desktop*